# What does a dot before range() mean?

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone explain me why is this

```
If Range("BJ" & i) - Range("R" & i) = 0 Then
    Range("BJ" & i) = "OK"
Else
    Range("BJ" & i) = "NOK"
End If
```

different from this? What do these dots mean?

```
If Range("BJ" & i) - Range("R" & i) = 0 Then
    .Range("BJ" & i) = "OK"
Else
    .Range("BJ" & i) = "NOK"
End If
```

Comment: When using a `.` - you are referring to a previous `With` statement (which you did not include in your example) - and without it, you are referencing the `ActiveSheet` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement - your example is also a bad one, since you are mixing the two, which can cause all kinds of problems if you aren't careful.

Comment: Both are in pretty bad shape tbh. As mentioned above, the ranges prefixed with a dot are referring to a with block. Notice not all the ranges in bottom code don't actually have the with block. Depending on the rest of the code, it will not be intuitive what sheet the ranges in question actually exist on.

Answer (score 3):

`Range` isn't a language-level keyword: it's a class defined in the `Excel` type library.

But you don't invoke *classes* in VBA (or any language I know) - you invoke *members*, and members belong to *objects*.

`Range` is a *property* of the `Worksheet` class, that returns an object whose type is `Range`.

When your host application is Excel, the `Excel` library is automatically referenced, and the global scope starts including hidden objects, like `[_Global]`, whose members include a `Range` property.

If you're **not** in a worksheet module, then an unqualified `Range` is property of some hidden global-scope object that's implicitly working off whatever `Worksheet` happens to be the current `ActiveSheet`, itself implicitly belonging to whatever `Workbook` object happens to be the current `ActiveWorkbook`.

If you **are** in a worksheet module, then an unqualified `Range`  member calls is implicily referring to *that sheet*'s `Range` property, and so the implicit qualifier is `Me`.

That means exactly what an unqualified `Range` member call does, depends on  what module the code is written in. **And that is terrible**, because you want a VBA instruction to do what it says, and say what it does - an instruction that does this, will do exactly the same thing regardless of what module it's written in.

So, consistently qualify all `Range` member calls. Always, all the time - just like you know to stick `Option Explicit` at the top of every single module, always, all the time.

The `.Range` calls, as others mentioned in comments, *are* qualified: these are member calls made against a `With` block variable (assuming your code compiles):

```
With SomeSheet
    .Range("A1").Value = 42
End With
```

Code that *sometimes* qualifies `Range` (and `Cells`, `Columns`, `Rows`, `Names`, ...and other `Worksheet` member calls), and *sometimes* don't, are extremely frail and bug-prone. [Rubberduck can help you locate implicit ActiveSheet references](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference).

Also note the implicit member calls in both of your snippets: the `Range` object isn't "equal to" another `Range` object - what's actually going on, is implicit member calls to `Range.Value`<sup>1</sup>, and it's the `.Value` of either `Range` object that's getting subtracted here:

> ```
> If Range("BJ" & i) - Range("R" & i) = 0 Then
> ```

In other words:

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("BJ" & i).Value - ActiveSheet.Range("R" & i).Value = 0 Then
```

Note that `Range.Value` returns a `Variant` that will be a `Variant/Double` if the cell contains any numeric type... but will be a `Variant/Error` given any cell error value (e.g. `#N/A`) - and you can't do math on `Variant/Error`. Consider validating whether the values are error values, using the `IsError` function.

---

<sup>1</sup> actually the default member of `Range` is a hidden property aptly named `[_Default]`. Depending on how it's used and parameterized, it returns different things. In *this* case, that's `Range.Value`. Given arguments, it would be `Range.Item`.